# How to log the failed records while insert the data in bulk mode

Tags: database, exception, mule

I am inserting the data in bulk mode.I want to insert the data from one db table to another db table. I am using Scatter-gather message processor.I have 10 records in source db table, in this 10 records the second record has some invalid data (like firstname is null) remaining 9 records are valid data, but in my target db table firstname column is not null. While inserting these 10 records into target db, its throwing the error as firstname is not null. How to identify particular record has invalid data using exception handling in mule. I am new in mule esb. Can anyone help on this scenario.`

### %output application/java

payload map
{
    id : $.Id,
    customerid : $.Customerid,
    address : $.Address,
    dob : $.Dob,
    firstname : $.Firstname,
    lastname : $.LastName,
    middlename : $.Middlename,
    phoneno : $.Phoneno,
    batch : $.Batch,
    recorddate : $.RecordDate

}]]>
        
        
        
            
                
                
                    
                
                
            
            
                
                
                    
                
                
            
        
        
    `

Answer (score -1):

Kindly post the exception message you are getting along with your xml flow.

**But as of now i may give below suggestion.**

Use a **collection splitter** to split and process each records.

catch the exception in the error handling block using the context `#**[Exception.causedBy(your exception class)]**`

After this kindly configure your strategy what to do in case of this exception happens.

In your case log your information with any **column value** or any **record id** that is unique for every message.This may help you out to see on which particular record your exception has occurred.

Thanks!

Comment: Now xml is available. Please refer then let me know. How to split the valid records and invalid records. The exception what i am getting is "Exception was found for route(s): 0. Message payload is of type: ArrayList".

Comment: If you split the records then no use of bulk mode

Comment: There is no Xml visible! can you make sure.